# How to get result of sql query executing on json file in s3 bucket from c# client?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am able to access S3 bucket from the c# client.
I have stored test.json in S3 bucket.
I have used below link to access S3 objects -
http://docs.ceph.com/docs/giant/radosgw/s3/csharp/

I want to run SQL query on "test.json" from the c# client and get the result back.
I am getting a response from the cloud but not able to convert it into a proper format so that I will have expected result. 
Please help with this.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/amazon-s3-select-support-in-the-aws-sdk-for-net/

```
 public async Task<ISelectObjectContentEventStream> GetSelectObjectContentEventStream(){
      var response = await s3Client.SelectObjectContentAsync(new SelectObjectContentRequest(){
                Bucket = "test.notification",
                Key = "test.json",
                ExpressionType = ExpressionType.SQL,
                Expression = "select * from S3Object s",
                InputSerialization = new InputSerialization()
                {
                    JSON = new JSONInput()
                    {
                        JsonType = JsonType.Document
                    }
                },
                OutputSerialization = new OutputSerialization()
                {
                    JSON = new JSONOutput()
                }
            });

            return response.Payload;
        }
```

By running query i am expecting the whole json data in file.